# R foreach : Number of threads reduce to 1

Tags: r, foreach, domc

Consider a sample code

```
library("foreach")

 library("doMC")

 library("multicore")

 multicore:::detectCores()

 registerDoMC(cores=6)

 alpha <- foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% {
  ...
 }
```

When I use top, on launch the number of threads is say 6. The amount of work for each thread is substantial. But, the number of threads quickly drops down to 5,4,3,2 and then 1. I guess from then on the execution is serial. I don't understand why ?

Cheers

Comment: Can you post the code in your `%dopar%` expression or at least provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Also, if you are returning a lot of data from the 6 processes to your main process, this will cause a considerable amount of overhead that won't execute in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the number of threads is reduced while you have serial tasks, but the same threads will be waiting. It seems some threads have finished working in your case.

Comment: I figured it out. The amount of work for each thread was unequal. It was not obvious from the code. Realized it only after timing each loop iteration separately. Thanks.